Converting the Bold, Italicized, Bold & Italicized text in a Word doc to their markdown equivalent without the enclosing asterisk moving to next para
OK so I've got a word document. It has a bunch of text some normal some that is in italics, some that is bold, and some that is both bold and italics.
I want to go through the entire document and replace the italics (or encapsulate it) with the same thing closed up in asterisk.
eg. Italics = *Italics*, Bold = **Bold**, BoldandItalics = ***BoldandItalics***. 

I don't want to convert the whole thing into a markdown format, just these three things.
I've tried using the Find and Replace function to select text that is Italicized but not Bold and replaced with *^&*. Replaced the bold with **^&** and the ones that are both with ***^&***.
The problem is that every time I do it. Word pushes the closing asterisk(s) to the next paragraph.
Eg. Before Find and Replace:
googoogaga
After Find and Replace:
*googoogaga
*

(The above end result can still stay italicized in word. That isn't an issue, but since Stack Overflow apparently uses Markdown formatting here just wanted to make it clear.)
It's been annoying the stuffing out of me for a long time. I tried getting help form ChatGPT and it suggested some stuff with VBA, but suffice to say it didn't work and was having the same problem.
Edit (Comment Response to Macropod):
It almost worked perfectly!
However it seems to screw up bigger paragraphs:
Warrior (Light) – Basic starting class. A light-class warrior focused on quick attacks, evasion, and finesse. While faster than both the medium and heavy variants, it comes with a decrease in attack power and survivability. Mainly uses weapons such as rapiers, daggers, small hatchets, and throwing weapons. Stat bonuses: +2 Agi, +1 End, +1 Str, +1 Vit, +1 Free Point.
Result after using the Code:
***Warrior (Light) – Basic starting class. A light-class warrior focused on quick attacks, evasion, and finesse. While faster than both the medium and heavy variants, it comes with a decrease in attack power and survivability. Mainly uses weapons such as r**ap****iers, daggers, small hatchets, and throwing weapons. Stat bonuses: +2 Agi, +1 End, +1 Str, +1 Vit, +1 Free Point.***


You could duplicate the Find expression (see edit to previous answer), but even that has its limits.
Here is a more robust approach. All it requires is that there is at least a space, tab, line break or paragraph break between changes in formatting.
Sub ApplyMarkDown()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Rng As Range
Dim ArrBold(), ArrItal(), ArrMark()
ArrBold = Array(True, True, False)
ArrItal = Array(True, False, True)
ArrMark = Array("***", "**", "*")
With ActiveDocument.Range
  'Clear formatting on final paragraph break
  With .Characters.Last.Font
    If .Italic <> False Then .Italic = False
    If .Bold <> False Then .Bold = False
  End With
  'Clear Table cell/row markers
  For i = 1 To .Tables.Count
    With .Tables(i).Range
      For j = 1 To .Cells.Count
        With .Cells(j).Range.Characters.Last.Font
          If .Bold = True Then .Bold = False
          If .Italic = True Then .Italic = False
        End With
      Next
      For j = 1 To .Rows.Count
        With .Rows(j).Range.Characters.Last.Font
          If .Bold = True Then .Bold = False
          If .Italic = True Then .Italic = False
        End With
      Next
    End With
  Next
  'Clear Table paragraph breaks, line breaks & tabs
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Text = "[^13^l^t]"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Font.Italic = True
    .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
For i = 0 To 2
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Font.Italic = ArrItal(i)
      .Font.Bold = ArrBold(i)
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      'Ensure starting punctuation is formatted
      Do While .Characters.First.Previous Like "['""‘“]"
        .Start = .Start - 1
      Loop
      Do While .Characters.Last Like "[""'”’.,:;!(?)]"
        .End = .End + 1
      Loop
      If .Font.Italic <> ArrItal(i) Then .Font.Italic = ArrItal(i)
      If .Font.Bold <> ArrBold(i) Then .Font.Bold = ArrBold(i)
      'Ensure starting spaces are not formatted
      Set Rng = .Duplicate
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      Do While .Characters.First.Next Like "[ " & Chr(160) & "]"
        .End = .End + 1
        If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
      Loop
      If .Start > ActiveDocument.Range.Start Then
        Do While .Characters.First.Previous Like "[ " & Chr(160) & "]"
          .Start = .Start - 1
          If .Start = ActiveDocument.Range.Start Then Exit Do
        Loop
      End If
      If .Font.Italic <> False Then .Font.Italic = False
      If .Font.Bold <> False Then .Font.Bold = False
      .Start = Rng.End
      'Ensure ending spaces are not formatted
      Do While .Characters.Last.Previous Like "[ " & Chr(160) & "]"
        .Start = .Start - 1
      Loop
      Do While .Characters.Last.Next Like "[ " & Chr(160) & "]"
        .End = .End + 1
      Loop
      If .Font.Italic <> False Then .Font.Italic = False
      If .Font.Bold <> False Then .Font.Bold = False
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
Next
'Apply MarkDown tags
For i = 0 To 2
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Font.Italic = ArrItal(i)
      .Font.Bold = ArrBold(i)
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      Set Rng = .Duplicate
      With Rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .InsertAfter ArrMark(i)
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
      End With
      Set Rng = .Duplicate
      With Rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertBefore ArrMark(i)
        .Font.Italic = False
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
      End With
      .End = Rng.End
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


That didn't work. In fact I think there might be a looping error since it keeps getting the doc to hang. (the not responding error)

Actually it might be something on my end since even the previous bit of code isn't working now? Well the first one is running but it doesn't seem to be doing anything?
Edit: Oh, I see you edited the initial comment. Well the edited version doesn't seem to do anything.

Looking closely at the changes the first code you gave me made. I can see that it is always paragraphs with more than 3 lines that are having problems. Ones that are 3 lines and below seem to be completely fine.

I've revised the above code somewhat. Try it now. All it requires is that there is at least a space, tab, line break or paragraph break between changes in formatting. I've also added a couple of lines to color the start & end of each tagged range green and red, respectively. You can comment-out/delete those lines once you're happy with how the code works.

I uh got a "Run time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"?

The code works fine for me. Unless you can tell me what line the error occurred on and what the code was processing at the time (for which you might insert .Select at an appropriate place above the code line that produces the error, I can't say what might need revision.

Never found out what was wrong with the new code. As I was going through all the iterations of code, I found that the extra asterisk being applied by the original piece of code had certain patterns so I just used Find and Replace in Ms Word to get rid of then them like so { ([A-Za-z0-9 ])**([A-Za-z0-9 ]) } and so { (**)(??)(****) }

I suspect the problem was because your document didn't meet the minimum requirements I'd specified - All it requires is that there is at least a space, tab, line break or paragraph break between changes in formatting.

Simple:
Sub ApplyMarkDown()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Font.Bold = True
  .Text = "[!^13^l]{1,}[!^13^l]{1,}"
  .Replacement.Text = "**^&**"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  .ClearFormatting
  .Font.Italic = True
  .Replacement.Text = "*^&*"
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


It worked almost perfectly. Worked for smaller segments of txt but the bigger paras are having problems. I edited the main Post with the example cause i'm too much of a noob to try and do it in a comment.
Notice the segment with the word "rapier". There are similar problems in many other paras of similar length.

The issue with the original code comes down to a wildcard limitation affecting strings longer than 255 characters. By adding the second [!^13^l]{1,}, the limit is doubled, but that's as far as that approach can get you.

This one works perfectly for lines of code with more than 4 lines (>255 characters like you said), but completely ignores anything with less than 4 lines.
